#  how open port 1450 in using sockets in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets

Code server I have server listen on port 1450:

//Using UDP sockets

```
  clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            EndPoint ourEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1450);
            //Listen asynchronously on port 1450 for coming messages (Invite, Bye, etc).
            clientSocket.Bind(ourEP);
            //Receive data from any IP.
            EndPoint remoteEP = (EndPoint)(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));

            byteData = new byte[1024];
            //Receive data asynchornously.
            clientSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData,
                                       0, byteData.Length,
                                       SocketFlags.None,
                                       ref remoteEP,
                                       new AsyncCallback(OnReceive),
                                       null);
```

but code on not open port 1450 and client connect:

```
  otherPartyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtCallToIP.Text), 1450);
                otherPartyEP = (EndPoint)otherPartyIP;
```

When i run code client and server in lan network it's ok. but run over network i check port 1450 in lan not open. tell me how open port 1450 in code server? thanks

Comment: Sounds like a firewall is getting in the way.

Comment: Are you stuck behind a packet-mangling firewall such as a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) firewall?

Comment: I agree with @EricJ. I don't think windows firewall blocks localhost ports at all; can you telnet to localhost:1450? If so, it's a firewall blocking your other IP's.

Comment: This is a UDP socket, you can't `telnet` to it.

Comment: I opened port 1450 in firewall, the problem is with the server code it's not listen port 1450

Comment: i have add port forward 1450 to router.
if i use code : 
TcpListener tcpServerListener = new TcpListener(1450);
            tcpServerListener.Start(); //start server it's listen ok on port 1450

Comment: but use
EndPoint ourEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1450)
  Socket.Bind(ourEP);
it's not listen on port 1450?

Comment: @NguyễnVănThắng: Are you trying to use TCP or UDP? You seem to have TCP in one place and UDP in others.

Comment: i use UDP with both server and client

Comment: when i run  netstat:
netstat -a -p UDP
Console write :
Active : UDP;
IP local: 192.168.1.3:1450
State : not show